# PHP Session fails on sub-domains

Tags: php, html

So I had a login/session system set up that worked perfectly for a good while.  However, within the last few days the sessions fail to carry to the sub-domains.

I have been using the following above the session_start call:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
```

Again, this worked fine.  You could log in at the base domain then move to a sub-domain and the session carried over.  Or you could log in at a sub-domain and move to others fine.  Example:

- Login at domain.com works
- Move to subdomain.domain.com does not
- Move to domain.com/subdomain works

No changes have been made at all to this script.  It just fails.  Perhaps the host is responsible?

**EDIT:**
Even if you log in on the sub-domain, the PHP session is created but doesn't work.  No $_SESSION array data works, etc., though you can see the PHP session in the browser's cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.  It seems my session.save_path in PHP.ini was set to /tmp which, for whatever reason, wasn't letting my subdomains work or access the session files.

I changed the PHP.ini to a new folder in the html hierarchy and it worked.

Still using the session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com'); and all my previous settings. So my code was fine, somehow the save path stopped working.  Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **ini_set()** function, like:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain',
substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."),100) );
```

Or try using **.htaccess**

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .domain.com
```

OR try setting secure param to false , like

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com', false, false);
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  I actually tried that before using...

    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.coaguco.com');

But it didn't work then.  The above session_set_cookie_params worked great for many months, as I mentioned in the original post.  And it works fine on the base domain or the subdomains as folders, ie. domain.com/subdomain, but not on the sub-domains directly anymore, ie. subdomain.domain.com

Comment: That just causes 500 errors.  But it's not really a problem with the PHP session itself.

Comment: can you check this:: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#104678, that might help in solving the issue...?

Comment: Mmm, that link seems to be a more verbose way of doing the stuff above.  And it's not that the session thing doesn't work, it worked fine for a long time.  No changes have been made to it, it just stopped working.  Curious if anyone knows of something that would affect it.

Comment: What browsers have you tested it under? It's possible by accident or through an extension/plugin its blocking cookies from the subdomain for privacy or security reasons. Try another browser, preferably a fresh profile with default settings.

Comment: Just tried it and it is no different.  This issue does not make any sense to me...